# vlock: sudo user prompted for root password

Tags: tmux

My system has TMUX with (lock-command vlock) so vlock is executed after a timeout.
The issue is that if a non-root user is running a lengthy sudo command (ie. sudo bash) and vlock is activated, they are prompted for their password AND the root password.

The user does not have the root password so they are essentially locked out of their session.

Is there a way to configure vlock or tmux to ONLY prompt for the user's password in this situation?

Comment: I'm not sure how you are getting this situation. tmux should run vlock on the client where the user is not root, so to unlock it you give the user password. That should be enough. If you are getting a second prompt, then something has also run a second vlock inside the bash shell that is under id root. What is starting this unnecessary second vlock?

Comment: I am implementing this by adding "[ -n "$PS1" -a -z "$TMUX" ] && exec tmux" to "/etc/bashrc".  Thus when I do something like "sudo bash", it starts a second tmux (as root).  I have to tell sudo to keep environment to solve the issue

Comment: You might try changing the `lock-command` in your `~/.tmux.conf` to check
if you are running under sudo, and if so to do another sudo back to the
original user before running vlock. Something like:
`set-option -sg lock-command 'if [ -z "$SUDO_USER" ];then vlock;else sudo -u $SUDO_USER vlock;fi'`